# Sending file (client to server and server to client)

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I have client.c and server.c , I'm trying to send a file from client to server and from server to client...
The file is received by the server but when the server sends the file , the client stops or does not receive the file ,
The sendFile() function:

```
void sendfile(int fd,char* filename)
{
    char buff[0x1000]; 
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "rb"); 
    if (!file)
    {
        printf("Can't open file for reading"); 
        return;
    }
    while (!feof(file)) 
    { 
        int rval = fread(buff, 1, sizeof(buff), file); 
        if (rval < 1)
        {
            printf("Can't read from file\n");
            fclose(file);
            return;
        }

        int off = 0;
        do
        {
            int sent = send(fd, &buff[off], rval - off, 0);
            printf("Sending ...\n");
            if (sent < 1)
            {
                printf("Can't write to socket");
                fclose(file);
                return;
            }
            printf("[SendFile]Fisierul a fost trimis!\n");
            off += sent;
        }
        while (off < rval);
    } 
 fclose(file);
}
```

The getFile():

```
void getFile(int fd,char* filename)
 {
    int rval; 
    char buff[0x1000]; 
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "w+"); 
    if (!file)
    {
        printf("Can't open file for writing");
        return;
    }

    do
    {
        rval = recv(fd, buff, sizeof(buff), 0);
        if (rval < 0)
        {
            printf("Can't read from socket");
            fclose(file);
            return;
        }

        if (rval == 0)
            break;

        int off = 0;
        do
        {
            int written = fwrite(&buff[off], 1, rval - off, file);
        printf("[server]Writing %d bytes\n",written);
            if (written < 1)
            {
                printf("Can't write to file");
                fclose(file);
                return;
            }

            off += written;
        }
        while (off < rval);
    printf("[server]File received!\n"); 
    }  
    while(1);
    fclose(file); 
 }
```

The client main():

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int sd;
  struct sockaddr_in server;

  if (argc != 2)
    {
      printf ("[client] Sintaxa: %s <filename>\n", argv[0]);
      return -1;
    }

  if ((sd = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1)
    {
      perror ("[client] Eroare la socket().\n");
      return errno;
    }

  server.sin_family = AF_INET;
  server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
  server.sin_port = htons (port);

  if (connect (sd, (struct sockaddr *) &server,sizeof (struct sockaddr)) == -1)
    {
      perror ("[client]Eroare la connect().\n");
      return errno;
    }
    sendfile(sd,"test.cpp");
    printf("File sent\n");
    getFile(sd,"server.c");
    close (sd);
}
```

The loop from server.c

```
while (1)
    {
      int client;
      int length = sizeof (from);

      printf ("[server]Asteptam la portul %d...\n",port);
      fflush (stdout);

      client = accept (sd, (struct sockaddr *) &from, &length);

      if (client < 0)
      {
      perror ("[server]Eroare la accept().\n");
      continue;
      }

    if((pid=fork()) == 0 )
    {

    getFile(client,"test.cpp");
        sendfile(client,"server.c");
        printf("File sent\n");
    close(client);
  } 

 }
```

Comment: Don't do `while(!feof(...))` because it will in almost all cases not work as you expect it to. The reason is that the end-of-file flag is not set until *after* you try to read from beyond the file, which means such a loop will iterate once too many. Instead do e.g. `while ((res = fread(...)) > 0)`

Comment: Also, you might want to read about the Linux system call [`sendfile`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sendfile.2.html).

Comment: Where exactly does the program hang? Does any of the calls signal an error before that? Which error does it signal? What if you remove the fork() code and just write two separate executables?

Comment: the fork is used to make the server concurrent...when i delete the line getFile(sd,"server.c") from client.c , the program ends correctly and the server executes  the line with printf("File sent\n");

Comment: I know what `fork()` does, the idea behind my suggestion was rather to reduce the complexity by removing this part. Further, what if you replace the file input with fixed values? Also, concerning where it hangs, your answer isn't helpful. You could just as well have said that it hangs somewhere in `main()`. You have to circle in further on the call that blocks.

Answer (score 3):

To Start with.

1. accept(), connect(), recv() .. all are blocking calls so in theory your program can get blocked anywhere in these calls until you use non blocking sockets. From the program it looks like you are using blocking sockets
2. I would suggest you to read a good socket programming tutorial like this one first **https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/**

Secondly

I would suggest you to have a tool like wireshark or any other packet analyzer tool running to debug your problem.

Lastly you can do something like the following code snippets to try

1. Set sockets to non blocking mode using fnctl API call.

   ```
   int rc = fcntl(newFd, F_GETFL,0);
   rc |= O_NONBLOCK;
   rc = fcntl(newFd, F_SETFL,rc);
   ```
2. Poll the socket for events You can use something like select,poll for the
   same. Here is a nice example for select in the Beej's tutorial.
   **https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/html/multi/selectman.html**
3. Handle errors correctly. Non blocking sockets can return a EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK error which has to be handled correctly. The error means the socket is not readable or writable at the moment look for events and try again. Someting on the lines of.

   ```
     rval = recv(fd, buff, sizeof(buff), 0);
     if (rval < 0)
     {
          if((errno == EWOULDBLOCK)||(errno ==EAGAIN))
          {
              continue;
          }
          else
              //cleanup
      }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

tre problem was the `do { ... } while(1);` from getFile ...so I deleted the loop...